# spring data mongo db repository save

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

is save method of MongoRepository does save document one by one or it uses the bulk insert feature of mongo . problem i am facing is , i am passing ist of 1000 documents to repository but nothing is changes in context of performance.

```
Interface MongoRepository<T,ID extends Serializable>

save

<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entites)

Specified by:
    save in interface CrudRepository<T,ID extends Serializable>
```

not sure what its super class crudrespository is doing as that is specific to JPA and not mongo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses bulk insert. Take for instance MongoRepository implementation - [SimpleMongoRepository#save](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/support/SimpleMongoRepository.java#L88) method. In case of insertion, it will invoke `insertAll` from `MongoOperations` and implementation of `MongoOperations` is `MongoTemplate`. And now you can take a look at [MongoTemplate#insertAll](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java?source=c#L843) and you will see it invokes [MongoTemplate#doInsertAll](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java?source=c#L847) which performs bulk insert by calling [MongoTemplate#doInsertBatch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java?source=c#L879) method.

And yeah. Insertion of 1000 documents will probably not significantly reflect performance differences.